# Suppress Purchase Requisition quantity check

Tags: debugging, abap, sap-erp, purchase-order

I have a case where I need the Purchase Requisition (ME51N) to work even if the quantity is set to 0.

The standard Purchase Requisition does not allow this in SAP. How can I find out while debugging where and how to make the enhancement changes, or change the standard code so this can be allowed? I have been debugging in SE38 --> SPROX_SERVICE_INTERFACE_TEST_I

FM: BAPI_REQUISITION_CREATE

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use BAdi `ME_PROCESS_REQ_CUST` for enhancing item validation logic.
It has methods **PROCESS_ITEM** and **CHECK** which may be helpful to you.

[Here is](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/Purchase+Req.+Line+item+Data+manipulation+using+BADI+-+ME_PROCESS_REQ_CUST#PurchaseReq.LineitemDatamanipulationusingBADI-ME_PROCESS_REQ_CUST-SampleCodeinBADI-Method) the implementation sample code and here is appropriate SAP note: [611175](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/611175) .

Although, I didn't find how to suppress standard checks (they are conducted before BAdi ones), you can play around **PROCESS_ITEM** method and try to change some values one-the-fly.